# Fire inline on trigger with FancyApp

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I wanted to know if there was a way to fire the elements in an inline only after a person clicks open the FancyApp. The reason I ask is because I have multiple thumbnails that launch their own inlines that contains Vimeo embeds, Gum Road Embeds and other Inline Data.

The problem I have now is that when I open a page it loads everything in the inlines that is not yet seen by the user, which could be very taxing on my server.

Please let me know on what I can do to keep the inline content from being called when the website is visited.

I am using the latest version of fancy box and I have 'preload : false,'

Thank you for you time. :)

Comment: I guess the only way is to place each of those inline contents in a separated html file and call them via ajax instead

Comment: I will have to figure out how to use Ajax with inputs that have variables like this:  echo '<iframe src="//player.vimeo.com/video/'.$id.'" width="750" height="425" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>'

Comment: Then call them as "iframe" instead of ajax/inline. Set the value of your current `src` in your `href` attribute. Also read http://vimeo.com/help/faq/sharing-videos/embedding-videos

Comment: For vimeo, call them on demand type `iframe` in fancybox http://jsfiddle.net/cwdvwLpn/

Comment: OK, you could still use inline BUT removing the `src` attribute of your (inline) iframes (so they won't impact your page load). Then pass the `src` value on a `data` attribute http://jsfiddle.net/cwdvwLpn/1/ or build the iframe on-demand passing any `data` attribute you may need http://jsfiddle.net/cwdvwLpn/2/

Comment: Thank you very much for your help :)  I tried both of your suggestions but neither loaded the video.  It does load the inline content though.  If you visit my page you can see the first suggestion being used.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69993/discussion-between-deyson-and-jfk).

Comment: Hello JFK.  So far so good.  However using your this example: http://jsfiddle.net/cwdvwLpn/1/ when I add an autoplay the video starts to play again after I close the fancy app.  Also the video starts to play if I make a video gallery and jump to the next video.  Thank you for all your help

Comment: You may want to remove it `afterClose` http://jsfiddle.net/cwdvwLpn/3/

Comment: Thank you for the quick responses.  It now seems that the video keeps play if I jump to the next video on Safari.  It works great in Chrome and Firefox:  http://mmt.staging.wpengine.com